# Get xml namespace (without triggering UnknownHostException)

Tags: java, xml, sax, xml-namespaces, xerces

I have some Java code that determines the namespace of the root-level element of an xml document using SAX. If the namespace is "http://sbgn.org/libsbgn/pd/0.1", it should return version 1. If the namespace is "http://sbgn.org/libsbgn/0.2", the version should be 2. So all the code does is read the first element, and set a variable based on the namespace. Here is the code:

```
private static class VersionHandler extends DefaultHandler
{
    private int version = -1;

    @Override
    public void startElement (String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
    {
        if ("sbgn".equals (qName))
        {
            System.out.println (uri);
            if ("http://sbgn.org/libsbgn/0.2".equals(uri))
            {
                version = 2;
            } 
            else if ("http://sbgn.org/libsbgn/pd/0.1".equals(uri))
            {
                version = 1;
            } 
            else
            {
                version = -1;
            }
        }
    }

    public int getVersion() { return version; }
};

public static int getVersion(File file) throws SAXException, FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    XMLReader xr;   
    xr = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();

    VersionHandler versionHandler = new VersionHandler();

    xr.setContentHandler(versionHandler);
    xr.setErrorHandler(versionHandler);
    xr.parse(new InputSource(
        InputStreamToReader.inputStreamToReader(
            new FileInputStream (file))));

    return versionHandler.getVersion();
}
```

This works, but has two problems:

1. It is inefficient, because the whole document will be parsed even though only the first element is needed.
2. More importantly, this code sometimes (apparently depending on firewall configuration) triggers a UnknownHostException like so:

```
    java.net.UnknownHostException: www.w3.org 
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown
    Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown
    Source)
    at
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown
    Source)
    at
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown
    Source)
    at
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown
    Source)
    at
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown
    Source)
    at
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(Unknown
    Source)
    at
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(Unknown
    Source)
    at
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown
    Source)
    at
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown
    Source)
    at
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown
    Source)
    at
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown
    Source)
    at
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
    Source)
    at
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
    Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown
    Source)
    at
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown
    Source)
    at org.sbgn.SbgnVersionFinder.getVersion(SbgnVersionFinder.java:57)
```

So my questions are:

1. Apparently this bit of code is connecting to the internet. How can I avoid that? Besides leading to problems with firewalls, it is also needlessly slow.
2. *Why* is it connecting to the internet? Please help me understand the logic here, there should be absolutely no need for it.
3. Is there a more efficient way to determine the namespace of the root element of an xml document?

Edit: here is a link to a sample document that I'm trying to parse this way: https://libsbgn.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/libsbgn/trunk/test-files/PD/adh.sbgn

Edit2: A note regarding to the solution of this bug: In fact the problem was triggered because the wrong document was being parsed, instead of the intended document, I was parsing an XHMTML document that does in fact refer to www.w3.org. Of course the solution is to use the correct document. Nevertheless, I found it useful to add this line:

```
 xr.setEntityResolver(null);
```

To prevent xerces from going over the internet when it's really completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to set the entity resolver. See the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/EntityResolver.html). Also, this [article](http://xml.apache.org/commons/components/resolver/resolver-article.html) seems relevant.

Comment: I just don't understand. At no point am I ever referring to anything from www.w3.org. I've added a link to a sample document at the end.

Comment: Finally I know what caused the problem, in this case a completely wrong XML document was passed, that did in fact refer to www.w3.org. So that explains the error message. The real solution was of course to pass correct XML, but still, I set  "xr.setEntityResolver(null);" to prevent it from unnecessarily going over the internet.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably connecting to the internet because your document is referring to a DTD or other external entity on the W3C web site. Earlier this year, W3C stopped serving these documents because they couldn't handle the traffic.

You can solve the problem of reading the whole document by throwing a SAXException from one of your callbacks once you've seen as much of the document as you need to see. Be sure in the code that calls the XMLReader.parse() method to distinguish this exception from exceptions thrown by the parser itself (for example, you could subclass SAXException: though not all parsers throw your original exception unchanged and you may need to experiment.)

Comment: "W3C stopped serving these documents because they couldn't handle the traffic" - well, I'm not surprised given that standard libraries are making these requests by default, without the programmer even knowing about it!

Comment: @amarillion, I share your indignation. I think its ludicrous that the standard docs are not packaged with XML parsers. Fetching the resources from classpath is such an elegant solution for static content like this.